# For loop only iterates once (simplehtmldom)

Tags: php, screen-scraping, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, phantomjs

I have a for loop that loops 3 times, and within the loop, a `shell_exec()` is done, calling a binary `phantomjs` and returning its output. This output is then passed into simplehtmldom's `str_get_html()`

**Problem:** When `str_get_html($html)` is involved in the for loop and `$html` consist of a webpage's HTML, only the first loop is executed, not the 2nd or 3rd. However, if I were to use some simple `<a>` tags for `$html`, the for loop iterates completely!

What is happening here, and how can I solve it?

*Note the difference in the 2 functions below (the one that works and the one that loops only once) is how one of them have a line commented out, the other has another line commented out instead.*

**Parent function** *(The `for` loop here does not iterate completely)*

```
public function action_asos() {


    // Site details
    $base_url = "http://www.mysite.com";

    // Category details
    $category_id = 7616;
    $per_page = 500;

    // Find number of pages in category
    $num_pages = 2;

    //THIS IS THE LOOP THAT CANNOT LOOP COMPLETELY!
    // Extract Product URLs from Category page
    for($i = 0; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
        echo "<h2>Page $i</h2>";
        $page = $i;
        $category_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/pgecategory.aspx?cid='.$category_id.'&parentID=-1&pge='.$page.'&pgeSize='.$per_page.'&sort=1';
        $this->extract_product_urls($category_url, $base_url);
    }
        echo "Yes.";
        flush();

}
```

**PHP Code (causes loop in parent function to loop only once)**

```
public function extract_product_urls($category_url, $base_url) {


    set_time_limit(300);
    include_once('/home/mysite/public_html/application/libraries/simple_html_dom.php');

    // Retrieve page HTML using PhantomJS
    $html = $this->get_html($category_url);

    // Extract links
    $html = str_get_html($html);
    //$html = str_get_html('<a class="productImageLink" href="asdasd"></a>');
    foreach($html->find('.productImageLink') as $match) {
        $product_url = $base_url . $match->href;
        $product_url = substr($product_url, 0, strpos($product_url, '&'));  // remove metadata in URL string
        $this->product_urls[] = $product_url;
    }

    echo "done.";
    flush();

}
```

**Helper functions**

```
/**
 * Gets the webpage's HTML (after AJAX contented has loaded, using PhantonJS)
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function get_html($url) {

    $url = escapeshellarg($url);    // prevent truncating after characters like `&`
    $script = path('base')."application/phantomjs/httpget.js";
    $output = shell_exec("phantomjs $script $url");

    return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($match = $html->find('.productImageLink')) {
    if (!is_object($match)) {
        break;
    } 
    . 
    . 
    .  
}
```

Comment: I get the error `Trying to get property of non-object` on the line `product_url = $base_url . $match->href;`

Comment: What's the value of `$match` when it throws the error? Do a `var_dump()`.

Comment: @Nyxynyx test for that value and `break` the loop if it's the invalid value.

Comment: A `var_dump($match)` inside the `while` loop spits out an extremely long string with alot of `RECURSION` text. How should I detect that `$match` is invalid?

Comment: If it's an object, it's valid. Your error is basically saying that at some point, `$match` is set to a non-object (probably `null`). Just add (as the first line in the loop) `if (!is_object($match)) { break; }`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I only get 1 iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @Nyxynyx What if you replace `break` with `continue`? That *may* create an infinite loop, but it may also work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the function that has the problematic for loop. Updated the post.

Comment: @Nyxynyx So, the `for` loop doesn't loop 3 times?

Comment: What happens if you `echo "$i, $num_pages";` after `$this->extract_product_urls($category_url, $base_url);`?

Comment: OK, now add that line directly above it, as well. You should get `0, 20, 21, 2`.

Comment: Hmmm...what if the first `echo` is the first line in the `for` loop?

Comment: This is bizarre. Clearly `$i <= $num_pages`.

Comment: Yes its strange. I think I just solved the problem. I need to do `$html->clear()` before working on the next page in the next iteration of the loop. Now it iterates through the entire `for` loop.

Comment: Oh. Well then...glad I could help?